# Can I add new package under the folder \scr in android?

Tags: android

I create an app with package name info.dodata.smsforward and eclipse create a default file construction just like Old.PNG.
[image]

I think the file construction under the folder \scr is not good, so I add three packages name BLL, DLL ,UI and place different classes file into different package name just like New.PNG.
[image]

My question are

A: Can I add new package under the folder \scr. You know there is only one package="info.dodata.smsforward" in  AndroidManifest.xml, I don't konw if only one package name is allowed in one android app.

B: Are my packages name too short? Do I need add my domain before package name BLL, DAL and UI. Will the short package name (such as BLL, DLL) conflict with other APP?

**Old ModePublic.java**

```
package info.dodata.smsforward;
public class ModePublic {

    public final static int DBVersion=2;
    public final static String DBName="smsforward.db";  
}
```

**Old AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.smsforward"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.dodata.smsforward.UIMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**New ModePublic.java**

```
package DAL;
public class ModePublic {   
    public final static int DBVersion=2;
    public final static String DBName="smsforward.db";
}
```

**New  AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.smsforward"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="UI.UIMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: yes you can have packages `info.dodata.smsforward` was your package name you place your .java files under a different package like  `info.dodata.smsforward.model
            info.dodata.smsforward.view
            info.dodata.smsforward.controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A.** Yes you can, as many packages you like as deep as you like.

**B.** There are no rules on this. It's hard for other people to understand what you mean with such short names. So when working with more people it's probably better to have nicer names. They won't conflict with other apps because they only exists within your initial package name directory. (manifest)

**Note:** The `AndroidManifest.xml` package name serves as a unique identifier for the application. And create the initial folders where classes are generated in. For example  `bin/classes/info/dodata/smsforward/`  Java packages are essentially just folders in src directory. You use those to bundle your interfaces and classes.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean the package names in AndroidManifest.xml must be unique? and package names in class files under folder \src can  as many?

Comment: Yes, but theres only 1 package name in your manifest. This is your app identifier. For example:  com.companyname.appname , it often looks like a reverse domainname app.company.com.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i agree with @tim

A: You can add any number of sub packages inside a package - no issues
B:

You cannot add the main package name as BLL or DLL. The android need a main package name with at least 2 identifiers, so as to apply the application in google play store.

Only main package should be with 2 identifier, all other package names can be any type.

But good android coding approach should have a main package as com.xxx and other packages will be like com.xxx.view, com.xxx.activity, etc

Comment: Sure, BLL cannot be used as main package name. But it wasn't the question. He asks if he needs to use the app package as prefix for others. Not If he can use DLL as application main package.  He *can* use shortnamed packaged without the app identifier as prefix.