# Add new package name to existing project

Tags: android, package-name

I'm developing an app at Android Studio. I changed a package name of my application and able to do so but my aim is to add a new package name to the existing project. As you see in image below, I am able to change **com.app.company.testapp**  but I want to add new package name to the existing package. Eg. I want to make package name  **com.app.company.domain.testapp**

How can I do this trick ?

[image]

Comment: I suggest adding android-sdk or android-studio or related.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :S

Comment: I edited your post for clarity. Pls review the word changes, hope it is fine. I actually have enough rep to make changes without me asking. But pls review.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean add more tags like android-sdk, android-studio or related. I m getting tired.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your root project directory

Select Refactor -> Rename

Select rename project and change the name there.

Also Select rename module and change it there as well. If you get an message saying module name already changed thats fine.

Now right-click on the project root folder again and select Open Module Settings.

Under the Modules section remove whatever folders are associated to your old project name.

Apply Settings and hit OK.

Restart Android Studio.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new package in your app then

- Right click on java folder and add new Package.

If you want to add a new package inside your previous package then

- Right click on previous package and add new Package.

If you want to change your package name then

- Select your previous package and hit **shift+f6** .Now you can rename your package.

Comment: When I choose your second suggestion my package name looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/DjT4b.png but I want to my package name looks like com.app.company.domain.testapp

Comment: when you create a java class inside the new package. the full name would be like **com.app.company.testapp.domain** . So you can do accordingly . you can create a new package taking 1 option

Comment: I know this but my aim is not creating new class. My aim is editing existing package name.. In order to clarify, I can give short example..Imagine I have one app with **com.example** package name...I want to change this package name to **com.company.example** package name. In android studio I am only able to change **com.example** package name. My question is how to add **company** tag to the existing package name ... so my package will be like this -->>com.company.example

Comment: Take the third option . `Select your package`. Either `right click` and `choose refactor` or directly hit `shift+f6 and select rename directory`. You can change it to anything like **com.salih.app** etc

Comment: wtih your solution someone only can change current package. My whole aim is add extra word to existing package name. I've did this trick now. I've created folder at project directory, It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at an SO link @ [Can I add new package under the folder \scr in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569044/can-i-add-new-package-under-the-folder-scr-in-android). The best answer is good info and another answer in the same link is good also. I learned something from this, and someday I might want to do this too.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Right Click on parent package (in your case **company**) you want to add Click on New -> Package -> Enter  name "**domain**" hit ok

Step 2 - .Now Move the child package to newly added package - means just click on testapp and drag drop into "domain" package, While you move the package this dialog is appears now note that never select second option 
[image]

Step 3 - .Now check AndroidManifiest.xml file you will see every activity, receiver ,service package name change to the package you maintained like - "**com.app.company.domain.testapp**"

Answer (score 0):

hi I just face the same problem and m glade I did found the solution as well.

go to your project folder and then where you want to add the package name just create a new directory after the existing one and name it what you want.